# Basis for Center of Group Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

There is already a similar post, that has an answer to my question, but it is quite short and I don't get it... So I am trying to show that 
\begin{align}
\{e_K |~ K \subset G~ conjugacy~ class \}
\end{align} is a basis for $Z(\mathbb{Z}[G])$. Serre even writes "one immediately checks that the $e_K$ form a basis", but even reading the other post  I don't see that...

My approach to this is:

Be $x \in Z(\mathbb{Z}[G])$, which is equivalent to: $x = gxg^{-1}$ for all $g \in G$. Writing 
$x = \sum\limits_{h \in G} \lambda_h h$, we get $x = \sum\limits_{h \in G} \lambda_h ghg^{-1}$. I don't really know how to go on at this point. I mean, I know that when $a,b \in K$ (same conjugacy class) you get $\sum\limits_{s \in K} \mu_s s = \mu\sum\limits_{s \in K} s$, since
\begin{align}
a = hbh^{-1} \Rightarrow \mu_a = \mu_b ~\forall a,b\in K
\end{align}
So all elements in the same conjugacy class have the same scalar.

But from here I don't really know how I can generate the $x = \sum\limits_{h \in G} \lambda_h ghg^{-1}$ with the $e_K$ ...

I would be really thankful, if someone could give me quite a basic proof that even I understand...

Comment: Could you link to the "similar post" you mention? This would help us in understanding your problem.

Comment: Ah yes, of course... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803614/center-of-group-algebra-finitely-generated/2805868#2805868

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $\sum \lambda_h h = \sum \lambda_h ghg^{-1}$ implies that $\lambda_h = \lambda_{ghg^{-1}}$ for all $g$, i.e $\lambda_h$ is constant along conjugacy classes. It follows that an element is the center can be written $ \sum \lambda_r c_r$ where $r$ runs along the conjugacy classes and $c_r = \sum_{h \in  r}h$. Since the $c_r$ are obviously linearly independant the claim follows.

Comment: But why do you need $x = \sum\limits_{h \in G} \lambda_h h = \sum\limits_{h \in G} \lambda_h ghg^{-1}$ ? I mean $\lambda_h = \lambda_{ghg^{-1}}$ does follow for all elements of the same conjugacy class anyway, doesn't it ?

Comment: I don't understand your objection. We want to show that a basis of $Z(\Bbb Z[G])$ is given by the $c_r$ (or $e_K$ with your notation). Essentially we need to show that any $x$ in the center can be written as linear combinaison of the $e_K$. This is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: Ohh, am I right in the thought that the $e_K$ even form a basis for the whole $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ ?

Comment: @Gilligans : certainly not ! For example, if $e_K$ is a conjugacy class with more than one element and $g \in e_K$, then $x=g$ can't be expressed as linear combinaisons of the $e_K$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I think I got it now :)

Comment: @Gilligans : you're welcome !